# Drop down on PHP form only working on first 2 items

Tags: php, forms

I've made a landing page with form. And made 4 options from drop down select. The form send fine, but for some reason, only the 2 values of $499 and $999 work, the $1999 and $4999 don't work. I must be missing something? The from works and sends fine, I receive it and the info is there except for the 2 last options on drop down...

Code is here:

```
 <select name="budget_selection" class="form-style-10-drop-down" required='required'>
                                    <option value="">- select -</option>
                                     <option value="$499">$499</option>
                                    <option value="$999">$999</option>
                                    <option value="$499">$1999</option>
                                    <option value="$999">$4999+</option>
                                </select>
```

PHP for the form is over here:

[http://pastebin.com/Ksznvmnq](http://pastebin.com/Ksznvmnq://)

Form in question is over here:

http://satearn.com/landing-page-jul-21/landing_page.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You repeated the same values

```
<option value="$499">$1999</option>
<option value="$999">$4999+</option>
```

It should be

```
<option value="$1999">$1999</option>
<option value="$4999+">$4999+</option>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your option values have the same values as the first two.